# Woocommerce rest api cannot list resources

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

There are a few posts on something similar, however I feel mine is unique.

So below I have included some screenshots for proof. I have followed the documentation and have restarted a few times now. Each time I restarted, I had been solving issues after issues. So lets start by what I have done

- Installed woocommerece
- Moved local development to https://carteapp.net ( my website ) for SSL certification for Basic authorization requested in the documentation
- Created both consumer key and secret key done in woocommerce settings
- used consumer and secret key in the body of postman
- Disabled any plugin that could potentially affect the api ( json api, json auth, My own custom plugins, user related plugns, etc)
- I bought a theme, so I did change the theme to the default one that it came with.

but my errors remain the same.

```
{
    "code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view",
    "message": "Sorry, you cannot list resources.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```

Here are some images for your reference
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5C5o.jpg
the consumer and secret key in the images no longer work. As I have cleaned and installed many fresh Wordpress now. If anybody had similar issue and found a solution to this. Please share them.

Websites that I had looked into

https://sgwebpartners.com/how-to-use-woocommerce-api/
https://help.robotninja.com/en/articles/2015407-woocommerce-api-authentication-issues
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#rest-api-keys

and many more, but those did not suggest any type of solution besides the usual, you have done something wrong and did not follow the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this a while back.

The solution was that apparently not all of the pages were secured with SSL

Thus I installed an add-on to make everything secure with SSL. Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are providing correct API url and Authorization you can use any of(basic auth or 0auth1.0).
[check screenshot]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2IlM.png

Comment: yes, i have done that, you can refer here https://imgur.com/a/DQHvfe5

Comment: Please, clear params from the link and hit.
"http://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products"
loke this